# Rails 3.2: using a collection partial with a non-standard foreign_key name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Rails 3.2.  I have a Deliverable model:

```
class Deliverable < ActiveRecord::Base
  # omitting attr_accessibles
  # omitting validations
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "owner_id"
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :event
end
```

And a User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # omitting attr_accessibles
  # omitting validations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects #writers assigned to the project
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects, join_table: "disclosed_users_projects" #users who have been disclosed on the project
  has_many :deliverables
end
```

This is my `index` controller:

```
def index
  @writers = User.where(is_team_member: true).order(:first_name, :last_name)
end
```

This is `index.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Calendar</h1>
<%= render partial: "writer", collection: @writers %>
```

This is `_writer.html.erb`:

```
<h3><%= "#{writer.first_name} #{writer.last_name} %></h3>
<%= render partial: "writer_deliverables", collection: writer.deliverables %>
```

This is `_writer_deliverables.html.erb`:

```
test
```

The problem is in `_writer.html.erb` where I get the following error when it tries to render the collection `writer.deliverables` because of the non-standard foreign key:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column deliverables.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...ELECT "deliverables".* FROM "deliverables"  WHERE "deliverab...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "deliverables".* FROM "deliverables"  WHERE "deliverables"."user_id" = 2
```

How can I tell Rails that the foreign key column name is actually `owner_id`?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, duh, I figured it out five minutes after posting.  I needed to add a foreign_key to my User model, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # omitting attr_accessibles
  # omitting validations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects #writers assigned to the project
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects, join_table: "disclosed_users_projects" #users who have been disclosed on the project
  has_many :deliverables, foreign_key: "owner_id"
end
```